# Malloc function sends garbage value to my header struct whenever printf() is used

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to create my own malloc function as part of an assignment.
I'm using the algorithm for Buddy Allocation to provide memory to any malloc requests.
In order to achieve this, I use the below malloc header:

```
struct MallocHeader
{
  struct MallocHeader *next;
  struct MallocHeader *prev;

  size_t size;
  int isFree;
};

typedef struct MallocHeader header;
```

I also have an arena to handle all the thread requests.

```
struct MallocArena
{
  header *freeList[8];
  size_t freeList_elements[8];
  size_t PAGESIZE;
  struct mallinfo stats;
  pid_t pid;
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_mutex_t arena_lock;
};
typedef struct MallocArena MallocArena;
```

Now based on my logic, different sizes of blocks (32,64,128...) are allocated in different array indices of *freeList*
For eg. If i get size of 33, it will be stored in the block of 64
freeList[0]-> size 32 -> nil
freeList[1]-> size 64 -> *some address value* isFree -> 0
.
.
.

Now my code works fine with normal inputs.
But if I have a printf() in my test file, it fails after that.

Just so people understand, in my logic, I  initialize my freeList[7] with an address which has been assigned some space using **mmap()**
And whenever there is a request for smaller allocations, the freelist[7] breaks into two halves and freeList[6] gets the two smaller sizes and freelist[7] becomes null.
And this continues as long as the correct space has not been allocated.

I know printf() uses malloc internally, and I can see while debugging I get a request for 1024 bytes to be allocated and it does allocate it.
But as soon as I start the next request, the address in the next and prev pointer changes to some unknown address.

```
arena->freeList[0]: 32: (nil): 
arena->freeList[1]: 64: (nil): 
arena->freeList[2]: 128: (nil): 
arena->freeList[3]: 256: (nil): 
arena->freeList[4]: 512: (nil): 
arena->freeList[5]: 1024: (nil): 
arena->freeList[6]: 2048: 0x555eb6db30f8:  0x555eb6db30f8 next:0x555eb6db38f8 prev:(nil) 1 size 2048--> 0x555eb6db38f8 next:(nil)             prev:0x555eb6db30f8 1 size 2048-->
arena->freeList[7]: 4096: (nil):
```

After a new request is inititated:

```
 Index :range: Start Address 
arena->freeList[0]: 32: (nil): 
arena->freeList[1]: 64: (nil): 
arena->freeList[2]: 128: (nil): 
arena->freeList[3]: 256: (nil): 
arena->freeList[4]: 512: (nil): 
arena->freeList[5]: 1024: (nil): 
arena->freeList[6]: 2048: 0x555eb6db30f8:  0x555eb6db30f8 next:0x616c616c616c6f68 prev:0x616c616c616c616c 1 size 2048-->Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The two outputs above, are just before the malloc function(called by printf()) ended and just after malloc function (called by me directly) was called.
I'm not sure why the address changes for the next and prev pointers.
Can someone enlighten me?
Also please let me know if you need more information, I'm pretty sure I'm missing a lot of minute details.

Comment: Maybe you can use a watchpoint in the debugger to trap when the next and prev pointers change.

Comment: Thanks, good advice. After exiting my malloc function, it goes into some fileops.c and genops.c and exits by saying "Couldn't write debug register: Invalid argument." Suddenly there is more stuff to research :(